# Using the replace verb in go modules for labix.org mgo

Tags: go

Using go modules, I would like to replace `labix.org/v2/mgo` with `github.com/globalsign/mgo`. The http://labix.org/mgo repository is unmaintained and has been forked to https://github.com/globalsign/mgo

- my code is stored outside `$GOPATH` in the directory `~/git/foo`
- I'm using go1.11
- other go modules are working (for example `go list -m all` lists other modules, the files `go.mod` and `go.sum` are updating automatically. See the full file below)

I've tried the following in the `go.mod` file:

```
replace labix.org/v2/mgo => github.com/globalsign/mgo v0.0.0-20181015145952-eeefdecb41b842af6dc652aaea4026e8403e62df
```

Running `go build` gives the following error:

```
build github.com/foo/bar: cannot find module for path labix.org/v2/mgo
```

The documentation in `go help modules` discusses *Pseudo-Versions* eg `v0.0.0-yyy..`, which I'm trying to use because the tags on https://github.com/globalsign/mgo are of the form `r2018.06.15` and not `v1.2.3` (semantic versioning).

In addition `go help modules` says:

```
Pseudo-versions never need to be typed by hand: the go command will accept
the plain commit hash and translate it into a pseudo-version (or a tagged
version if available) automatically. This conversion is an example of a
module query.
```

However I can't work out the command for generating a pseudo-version when I'm in the cloned `github.com/globalsign/mgo` (located at `$GOPATH/src/github.com/globalsign/mgo`). Hence the pseudo-version I've manually generated may be wrong.

The full `go.mod` file looks like:

```
module github.com/foo/bar                                                                                                                                     

replace labix.org/v2/mgo => github.com/globalsign/mgo v0.0.0-20181015145952-eeefdecb41b842af6dc652aaea4026e8403e62df                                                                          

require (                                                                                                                                                                                     
  github.com/DATA-DOG/godog v0.7.8                                                                                                                                                            
  github.com/alecthomas/assert v0.0.0-20170929043011-405dbfeb8e38 // indirect                                                                                                                 
  github.com/alecthomas/colour v0.0.0-20160524082231-60882d9e2721 // indirect                                                                                                                 
  github.com/alecthomas/repr v0.0.0-20181024024818-d37bc2a10ba1 // indirect
  ...                                                                                                                   
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [go edit -replace](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Edit_go_mod_from_tools_or_scripts) command, without modifying the line of the original package.
This way you don't need to know the exact [pseudo version](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions) beforehand, just the commit hash id.

So in your case, don't manually modify go.mod require section of "labix.org/v2/mgo", and run this command to append your commit "eeefdec" of your fork, on top of labix version:

```
$ GO111MODULE="on"  go mod edit -replace=labix.org/v2/mgo=github.com/globalsign/mgo@eeefdec
```

After the first time you build or test your module, GO will try to pull the new commit, and then will generate the "replace" line with the correct pseudo version for you. So then you'll see on the bottom of go.mod:

> replace labix.org/v2/mgo => github.com/globalsign/mgo v0.0.0-20181015135952-eeefdecb41b8

Answer (score 1):

When using the `replace` directive, leave the pseudo-version out.
It's also stated [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem), which points to an open issue.

Probably off-topic, but I've mostly used `replace` when I wanted to use a local version of some dependency. Why not `import` the forked lib which you'd like to use (instead of the original non-maintained one) and have mod resolve it properly?

Comment: Thanks @havelock, I'll check this out during the week. From memory, omitting version information gives errors. Also, rather than rewriting import everywhere (using sed) I actually want to practice this feature of mod -- substituting one library for another. In this particular case it's not a big deal, but in future I could see it being so - eg in a large automated build chain.

Answer (score 1):

The *source* being replaced (in this case `labix.org/v2/mgo`) also needs to be added to the require list with a version of `v0.0.0` (even though it won't be downloaded). In the replace the *source* doesn't need a version but the *target* does.

However I haven't worked out how to auto-generate the pseudo version for the *target* (`github.com/globalsign/mgo` in this case), so I still needed to manually generate it.

Here's a better go.mod file:

```
  1 module foo.bar/qux                        
  2                                                                                  
  3 replace labix.org/v2/mgo => github.com/globalsign/mgo v0.0.0-20181015145952-eeefdecb41b842af6dc652aaea4026e8403e62df
  4                                                                                  
  5 require (                                                                        
  6   github.com/DATA-DOG/godog v0.7.8                                               
  7   github.com/alecthomas/assert v0.0.0-20170929043011-405dbfeb8e38 // indirect    
      <snip>                 
 21   golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20181116024801-cd38e8056d9b // indirect              
 22   labix.org/v2/mgo v0.0.0                                                        
 23 )
```

Notice the require of `labix.org` on line 22; `go mod tidy` accepts this.

However I now come up against a *different* issue, the use of internal packages (referred to in issues like this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23970). I still haven't solved this new problem.

```
% go build main.go
/home/sonia/go/pkg/mod/github.com/globalsign/mgo@v0.0.0-20181015145952-eeefdecb41b842af6dc652aaea4026e8403e62df/auth.go:38:2:
use of internal package github.com/globalsign/mgo/internal/scram not allowed
```

Comment: did you solve the issue with internal package? i'm having the same issue

Comment: Trying to remember, I'm on holidays... 2 things I found useful: 1) to auto-generate the pseudo version number for packages, setup a dummy Go project that requires the package in a .go file, then after 'go mod tidy' the version number appears in go.mod for copy/paste 2) the internal packages issue - this was caused by the 'sub' package not following semantic versioning. If you get the 'parent' package working using previous 'go mod tidy' will auto pickup children; otherwise manually generate the version numbers using the previous trick, then write 'replaces' for all the sub packages :-(